# Node.js path.join removes leading period

Tags: node.js

I came home with a work project that I planned on fiddling with on my personal computer, I installed everything, using the exact same environment (Node v0.11.12), etc. Start the project, then I'm greeted with messages complaining that the config loader module cannot locate a file (that exists and is at the path exposed by the error).

Looking closer at the error, I realize that the problem is `path.join()`. Where

```
path.join('./foo/bar');
// 'foo/bar'
```

Which is not good. Why does `path.join` remove the leading period?

#### ** Note **

The above is simply an example. The program make use of the function like

```
var configFile = require(path.join(modulePath, 'conf', file));
```

for example, where `modulePath` is relative to the current working directory (i.e. `./app/module/`)

Comment: Those are equivalent. Are you sure you are in the working directory you think you are?

Comment: @Joe, I don't change directory, and I just tested in the Node console (ex: `node -e "console.log(require('path').join('./foo/bar'));"` which simply echo `foo/bar`)

Comment: That should still work. You should add some console logging to see what path you are actually trying to `require`

Comment: @Joe, I did, this is why I'm asking the question. And... it works just fine at work, but not on my home computer that is using the (so I think) the exact same settings. This question is beyond debug, and is more about "why does it do that?"

Comment: A path of `.` refers to the "current" path. So `./foo/./bar` *should* generally be equivalent to `foo/bar` (the canonical form) when resolved as a local file path, as non-absolute paths are implicitly relative. Which paths *work* and which paths don't for `configFile`? (That is, provide the input *and* output for the working/failing cases.)

Comment: @user2864740, the working solution would be to manually resolve the path using `process.cwd()` and pass an absolute path to `require`. Which, by the way, works if the leading period is still there. Let me rephrase this, `require('./foo/bar');` works, but not `require('foo/bar');`. But all this is, again, not a direct part of the question. My expectation is that `path.join()` "joins" paths, not resolve it in any way.

Comment: If there is a leading period then it is *not* an absolute path. However, I content the question is *about* `require` and not `join` - as the canonical form for `./foo/bar` *is* `foo/bar`.

Comment: @user2864740, yes, I know. The question is not about absolute or relative paths. It's about why `path.join()` removes the leading period.

Comment: Because the `foo/bar` *is* the canonical form for `./foo/././././bar/.` - and `path.join` returns the canonical form. The fact that the "period path component" is on the front (as opposed to somewhere else) doesn't matter.

Comment: 2022 here. So how to `require()` properly a path like that? Not using join at all I guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *correct* behavior, and is documented in the [Path.join](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2) documentation:

> Join all arguments together and *normalize* the resulting path.

It is *correct* because `foo/bar` *is* the normalized (canoncial) form of `./foo/bar`, just as it is the normalized form of `./foo/././bar/.` or `foo/baz/../bar`.

(Differences between `require('./foo/bar')` and `require('foo/bar')`, and any resulting problems of such, should be specifically addressed in a different question without `path.join`.)

Comment: Would you have an idea as to why I just got this error, while it's been working flawlessly at work for weeks? :)

Comment: @YanickRochon No idea. Any source changes or version updates?